# Totally override __init__ in inherited Class Python 3

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super

I have class `Game` and class `RecentGame` that is inherited from the class `Game`. I don't need my `__init__` in the class `RecentGame` to have anything in common with the class `Game`'s `__init__`, so I haven't used the `super()` function. But I do need this inheritance since I want to use methods of the class `Game`. PyCharm marks this as a warning and I want to know how to do it properly so it won't cause any warnings. Maybe I am doing it wrong at the first place?

Here's my code:

```
class RecentGame(Game):
    def __init__(self, dota_id):
        self.dota_id = dota_id
        self.info = requests.get(OPENDOTA_API_URL + f"players/{dota_id}/matches?limit=1").json()[0]
        self.detailed_info = requests.get(f"http://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{self.info['match_id']}").json()
```

This is the warning that PyCharm gives me:

> Call to __init__ of super class is missed

EDIT:
The class `Game` and the class `RecentGame` both have the same `self` attributes: `dota_id`, `info`, `detailed_info`. But they get their values using different ways. The class `Game` gets game info by its id while the class `RecentGame` gets info of the last player's game by his `dota_id`. So they are basically the same, the only difference is in semantic and in the ways they get their `info` and `detailed_info`. All needed methods are the same.

EDIT 2:
Here's my `Game` `__init__()` method:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, dota_id, game_id):
        self.dota_id = dota_id
        self.detailed_info = requests.get(f"http://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{game_id}").json()
        is_in_game = False
        for player in self.detailed_info['players']:
            if player['account_id'] == dota_id:
                is_in_game = True
                break
        if is_in_game:
            temp = requests.get(f"https://api.opendota.com/api/players/{dota_id}/matches").json()
            for match in temp:
                if match['match_id'] == game_id:
                    self.info = match
                    break
        else:
            raise PlayerNotInGameException
```

Comment: "I don't need my `__init__` in the class `RecentGame` to have anything in common with the class `Game`'s `__init__`, so I haven't used the `super()` function. But I do need this inheritance since I want to use methods of the class `Game`."—this sounds like a misuse of inheritance. Should `RecentGame` _really_ inherit from `Game`, or should it possibly have a `game` attribute that is itself a `Game`? Or possibly the `Game` class should have some kind of timestamp and an `is_recent()` method?

Comment: Please update your question with the `__init__()` method of `Game`. This should show you what you need to do.

Comment: @Chris. The approach in the question actually seems pretty reasonable, although most likely OP wants a classmethod of `Game` that just initializes state and returns a normal `Game` object.

Comment: Perhaps these methods you want to use should be extracted into a separate class. It sounds like `RecentGame` will use some methods, but if it used other ones, you'd crash.

Comment: "I don't need my `__init__` in the class RecentGame to have anything in common with the class Game's `__init__`" **Why do you believe this is the case**? Doesn't `Game`'s `__init__` assign any attributes to `self`? Shouldn't those attributes have values? If you haven't initialized the underlying `Game`'s data, *how do you expect its methods to work properly*?

Comment: I updated my question and provided some extra information about why I decided to use inheritance

Comment: It sounds like you need to refactor your classes to remove common code. Only to really know, you should update your question with the `__init__()` method of `Game`.

Comment: Sounds like you need `BaseGame` to be a common base class and for your two classes to inherit from that one.

Comment: @quamrana How should it look like? Do i need to use `super()` method while inheriting from it?

Comment: Yes, each of your classes should just create values how ever they need to and pass them into `super().__init__(...)` where `BaseGame` assigns them to the members.

Comment: You are not required by law to make your code PyCharm-clean.  It doesn't understand every situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```py
class BaseGame:
    def __init__(self, dota_id, info, detailed_info):
        self.dota_id = dota_id
        self.info = info
        self.detailed_info = detailed_info

    # rest of old Game class elided

class RecentGame(BaseGame):
    def __init__(self, dota_id):
        info = requests.get(OPENDOTA_API_URL + f"players/{dota_id}/matches?limit=1").json()[0]
        detailed_info = requests.get(OPENDOTA_API_URL + f"players/{dota_id}/matches?limit=1").json()[0]
        super().__init__(dota_id, info, detailed_info)
     # nothing else needed
```

I'm leaving Game as an exercise...